# Powershell Force windows service that has dependency service to stop

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm currently working on a powershell script to stop certain windows services and set its startup type to disabled.

My script works fine for services with `status stopped` however for services that has `dependency service running` cannot be stopped. I get bunch of errors. I tried to append `-Force` switch,it aint working too. What could be wrong.

Below is my script.

```
# Function defintion
function Shut_Services_Down {
    # Services array
    $services_to_shut_down = @("spooler", "XblGameSave", "Fax")
    
    # Loop each service in the array
    foreach ( $node in $services_to_shut_down ){

        Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled -Force

    }
    
}

# Call the function
Shut_Services_Down
```

error 1

```
Set-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force'.
At C:\users\admin\desktop\psscripts\services.ps1:9 char:71
+ ...  Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled -Force
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand

Set-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force'.
At C:\users\admin\desktop\psscripts\services.ps1:9 char:71
+ ...  Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled -Force
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand

Set-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Force'.
At C:\users\admin\desktop\psscripts\services.ps1:9 char:71
+ ...  Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled -Force
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

error 2, after removing `-Force` switch

```
PS C:\users\admin\desktop\psscripts> .\services.ps1
Set-Service : Cannot stop service 'Print Spooler (spooler)' because it has dependent services.
At C:\users\admin\desktop\psscripts\services.ps1:9 char:9
+         Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceHasDependentServicesNoForce,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

Solution

```
# Function defintion 
function Shut_Services_Down { 
    
# Services array     
$services_to_shut_down = @("spooler", "XblGameSave", "Fax")   
       
# Loop each service in the array     
foreach ( $node in $services_to_shut_down )
{          
Stop-Service -Name $node -Force -Confirm:$false          
Set-Service -Name $node -Status stopped -StartupType Disabled      
}      
}  

# Get-Service -Name "spooler" | Format-List -Property Name,DependentServices 

# Call the function 
Shut_Services_Down
```

Comment: Call `Stop-Service -Force` separately before calling `Set-Service`

Comment: Hi Mat, can you kindly edit the code, will there be a time wait  between `stop-service`  cmdlet and `set-service`?

Comment: `Stop-Service` won't return until the dependency chain is completely stopped, or it fails, if that's what you mean - so `Set-Service` won't be called while `Stop-Service` is still running

Comment: PLEASE - do not post anything more than SHORT bits of code  in comments. in your case ... add it to your Question.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, kindly have not understood your statement. Kindly can you reitarate.

Comment: Code in comments become unreadable very quickly. What Lee says is that you need to click the edit link beneath your question and add your new code in there as formatted text.

Comment: @Bernietechy - you have placed code - quite a bit of code - in a _comment_ ... and long sections of code do not belong in a comment. why? because you cannot properly format it. [*grin*] so ... PLEASE add that code to your Question, not in a comment to your Question.